# npm start command not working on Linux server

Tags: node.js, linux, reactjs

I have created one React project on Windows Machine. Which is working fine. I have deployed same code on Linux machine.

Where I am getting

```
Permission denied
npm ERR! storeperformance@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
```

I have tried replacing react-scripts with "scripts":

```
{ "start": "node ./node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start" }
```

After that I am getting

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
                                          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Please suggest.

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which node version you are using ? seems like it has no clue about arrow `=>`

Comment: @swapnesh -- v0.10.30

Comment: This version is very old and not supporting Arrow functions, try to update your node and then give a try\

Comment: Ok. I will try.

Comment: I have updated Node version, now it's working fine. Thanks @swapnesh